# Download file with changing name from FTP server in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have got a setup where a file is being placed in my FTP server directory regularly. I am looking for the best way to pull it into my Python script. The catch is that the name changes every time the file is deposited. I.e. the first file is `FILE0001.CSV`, the second is `FILE0002.CSV`, the third `FILE0003.CSV`, and so on. My current idea is to store a variable with value `1` in a txt, extract that variable, add one to it, use it to reference the file, and then re-store the variable. Something like this (assuming the txt with the value has already been created and is in the folder):

```
with open('count.txt') as fp:
    c = int(fp.read())

c = c+1

ftp = FTP('localhost')
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.cwd('dropoff')
with open('FILE000' + c + '.CSV', 'wb') as fp:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR FILE000' + c + '.CSV', fp.write)
ftp.quit()

with open('count.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(str(c))
```

This seems like a bit of a roundabout way to do it, is there is a better and/or more direct way?

There is no way to change the incoming file name or keep the name and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only the only file on the server, ask the server for its name and download it:

```
ftp.cwd('dropoff')

files = ftp.nlst() 
if (len(files) != 1):
    raise Exception("Expected only one file")

thefile = files[0]
with open(thefile, 'wb') as fp:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + thefile, fp.write)
```